# Select max(date) does not work if the rows have different values, I only want to fetch the row with the highest date

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

This is the code:

```
select security,max(dte),close,ask,bid,mid from k$prices
where to_char(dte,'MON-YYYY') = 'JAN-2021'
group by security,close,ask,bid,mid,dte
order by security,dte desc
```

Below is the result: I only want to get 2 rows, which has the highest date for each security (436 January 5 and 448 January 29) but because the values of the fields are different, all rows are still being shown. Please help me. Thanks

[image]

Comment: Remove dte from the GROUP BY clause, and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could rank all your rows first within the inline view t, then select only those that have rank 1 ( rnb = 1)

```sql
select security, dte, close, ask, bid, mid
from (
  select security, dte, close, ask, bid, mid, row_number()over(partition by security order by dte desc) rnb
  from your_table
)t
where rnb = 1
;
```